# typeorm generating extra column in select?

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

why the following typeorm query

```
const result6 = await getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .select('actor.name')
        .from(Actor,'actor')
        .innerJoin('actor.castings','casting')
        .where('casting.movieId = :id',{id:27})
        .getMany();
```

produces this result:

```
SELECT "actor"."name" AS "actor_name", "actor"."id" AS "actor_id" 
FROM "actor" "actor" 
 INNER JOIN "casting" "casting" ON "casting"."actorId"="actor"."id" 
WHERE "casting"."movieId" = $1
```

why actor.id is also selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just done some testing, and i noticed that the id is always included in the queries for some reason, but the returned values don't include it, it only includes what you put on the select.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but  the column on which join is performed is not required in selection. and moving select before getMany produces the same  query.

Comment: i just done some testing, and i noticed that the id is always included in the queries for some reason, but the returned values doesn't include it, it only includes what you put on the select.

Comment: You are right... why on earth they did like this.... anyways thanks for finding it out. Can you please edit your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured that the getRawXXX methods do not select the table id.